# How to print sem_t value in gdb?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, semaphore

Here is my code:

```
sem_post(&mysem);

foo(); // breakpoint here
```

I can call `sem_getvalue` to get value in the runtime.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
int sem_getvalue(sem_t *restrict sem, int *restrict sval);
```

But how to call `sem_getvalue()` in gdb?

Or maybe some other way to get value from `mysem` directly?

Comment: `sem_t` is not opaque.  You should be able to `print mysem` in gdb to see its contents.  You will then still need to figure out how to interpret the fields, of course, which is one of the primary things that `sem_getvalue()` does for you when you use that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: GDB does not provide you with your own call stack frame to add variables. You can call functions from the current stack frame at your current observation point. However, if your function requires pointers to variables, you have to provide the arguments. You can modify your program with global variables to allow you to use for those arguments. You could call malloc. But, you will need to pass in the address. But John is right, you can just print the semaphore variable itself.